# Get the values from a list of dictionaries which have dictionaries nested in them using python

Tags: python, json

I am loading objects from json file and putting it in a list. I want to access the value of "details". I have tried something like this -

```
    item_list = [{
    "text": "some text here",
    "timestamp": "Tue Jun 30 16:46:48 +0000 2020",
    "details": "{'id': '1278007086765522944', 'hash': ['e66d35b329a7c2cff66075eaf4530d13']}"}]

for d in item_list.iterkeys():
        print(d['item'])
```

but I am getting `UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'iterkeys'`

Comment: you don't need to add ' around '{' and '}', just {'item1':'value1','item2':'value2'} will be fine

Comment: 1- check the comment by @Kristaps , 2- the `iterkeys()` does not work on the list.

Comment: @Kristaps this the json file from a job i am getting and i have to process the same. I have to take each json object and put it in a list and then process it.

Comment: @Kristaps thanks, i have edited the json in my question.

Comment: @Hotshot02 no problem :) (oooh, so you're getting part of the json as a string) - iterkeys is a python 2 (?) way of getting the keys from a dictionary - your outer structure is a list (it's wrapped in [  ] instead of being wrapped in {  } - if you're looking to loop through the entries and access details you'll want to just do > > > 

      for d in item_list:
           print(d["details"]) < < < 
you can take a look at https://medium.com/@paulrohan/python-list-vs-tuple-vs-dictionary-4a48655c7934
)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that `item_list` is a list not a dictionary and `iterkeys()` only works on dictionaries.

Anyway, one solution is to perform the following steps:

- take each element in item_list (the elements would be dictionaries)
- get the list of values of each dictionary from above
- check the type of the value and if it is a dictionary itself, then extract the values of that dictionary and process them in any way you need

```py
for dict_item in item_list:
    for value in dict_item.values():
        if type(value) == dict:
            for target_value in value.values():
                # do whatever you need with the target_value
                print(target_value)
```

Make sure you also properly format your item_list (see @Kristaps comment).

**[Section added after the question was updated]**

I got it. So, somehow you get the dictionary embedded in a string.
In this case first thing you need to do is to convert that string to a dictionary. There are a few approaches for this. You can find interesting examples here:

- [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

I prepared a little example using `ast`:

```py
import ast 

for dict_item in item_list:
    for value in dict_item.values():
        try:
            # try to evaluate the value; the evaluation might raise some exception
            res = ast.literal_eval(value)
            if type(res) == dict:
                # dictionary found; do whatever you need with it
                print(res)
        except SyntaxError:
            # just continue to the next value
            continue
```

Comment: thanks, i have edited the json but i am still not able to get the "details" dict.

Comment: @Hotshot02, see my updated answer. Btw, I suggest you always specify the Python version that you are using. Some functionalities only work on Python 3 and don't work in Python 2 or the other way around. There might also be differences between minor versions of Python. So, it would be useful to specify your exact version.